# Opening file from directory in ruby using File.open

Tags: ruby, file-io, directory, cgi

I am relatively new to Ruby, I am trying to open a file in a way like:

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby
data_file = '~/path/to/file.txt'
file = File.open(data_file, 'r')
```

however I get "No such file or directory" (the file does exist in that directory).  It works if I put that path to the file as a command line argument such as:

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby
file = File.open(ARGV[0], 'r')
```

and then run from the command line like: ruby script.cgi ~/path/to/file.txt

Any ideas how to get it to work the first way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The path isn't getting expanded, but it does when you run it through the command line.  I believe in unix systems, the path is expanded prior to running the call, meaning:

```
ruby file.rb ~/path/to/file
```

is actually expanded to

```
ruby file.rb /home/user/path/to/file
```

You can validate this by running the following in your terminal (or create a ruby file with `p ARGV[0]` and run that):

```
echo "p ARGV[0]" | ruby "" ~/path/to/file #/home/user/path/to/file
```

You can use [File.expand_path](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-expand_path) to change `~` into `/home/user`

```
data_file = '~/path/to/file.txt'
file = File.open(File.expand_path(data_file), 'r')
```